# Javascript data model, cross reference

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I am receiving the following data structure:

```
{ 8: ['red', 'green', 'blue'] }
{ 10: ['red', 'green'] }
{ 12: ['green', 'blue'] }
```

From this data I need to be able to create an object model that will allow me to determine which colors are available in a given size, but also the reverse, which sizes are available for a given color.

I know I can create two data sets, and two functions to do the lookup but is there a more elegant way to do this with something like UnderscoreJS?

Comment: In its current form that is not a single JS structure. Is each of those lines an array element? Or are they supposed to be three properties of the same object? Or...?

Comment: Sorry I'm receiving a json result with objects that look like the above example. Assume an Array.

Comment: I don't see anything inelegant about parsing an object into two lookup objects. But, that's a seriously awkward data structure you have to work from. Do you have any control over the source data? It would almost be simpler to parse it from a string than to process it as an array of objects, each consisting of just a single arbitrarily named property.

Comment: @gilly3 I'm quite happy to use two lookup objects, but you know how things go with code reviews etc. You always want to see if there is a better way, and there are lots of talented people on SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using underscore or lodash*

```
var a = [
    { 8: ['red', 'green', 'blue'] },
    { 10: ['red', 'green'] },
    { 12: ['green', 'blue'] }
];
function getIndicesByColor(a,color){
    var list = _.assign.apply(this,a);
    return _.select(_.keys(list),function(v,k,l){return _.contains(list[v],color)})
}
getIndicesByColor(a,'red') // ["8", "10"]
getIndicesByColor(a,'green') // ["8", "10", "12"]    
getIndicesByColor(a,'blue') // ["8", "12"]
```

Comment: But how do I do the reverse? Find out which sizes are available in blue for example!